# Connections ending up in close_wait state and load is not balanced properly

Tags: apache, kubernetes, tcp, httpclient, connection-pooling

From service A , it calls a method is service B using Apache http client libraries postForEntity method and closeablehttpclient. A uses poolinghttpconnectionmanager also with values set for closed idle connections, socket time out , total connections , max connection per route. All the calls to Method in B is handled by only one K8s pod even though there are 2 cluster and 3 pods in each of it. No session affinity inside pods . No ingress controller ahead of B , ahead of A has. When checked the A pods during traffic ,  connection to B is ending up in close_wait. When the pod in B with load kills subsequent calls goes to new spinned up pod.